# Wireless not connecting (Or detecting) before actually installing ubuntu on MacBook Pro

Tags: wireless, macosx

Today I was attempting to install ubuntu on my MacBook as a separate partition. I was able to get ubuntu ready to install via a dvd, but I encountered a problem once I actually wanted to begin installing:

Ubuntu won't connect to my wireless internet (It only gives me an option to connect to wired) and it doesn't detect it either for all I know.

So therefore I have 2 questions:

1. How can I enable wireless before installing ubuntu in order for everything to work?
2. Could I install ubuntu without internet connection and then fix the problem (and install updates) later on, or would that just cause trouble?

All help is massively apprecitated!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact wireless card in your MacBook, it may require an additional driver or perhaps firmware. You might check 'Additional Drivers' to see if any suggestions are found there.

You can install Ubuntu without wireless perfectly well. Then provide details about your wireless from the terminal:

```
    lspci -nn
```

We can then determine the best driver or firmware for your wireless card.

Not all drivers and firmware are included by default because they are not all free and open source software. You are free, however, to install third-party software if you wish.